# Install Android SDK offline

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

I have installed Android studio 3.1.2 which is packaged without Android SDK. When I start Android studio, it tries to download SDK which is greater than 1GB. My connection speed is poor and the last three days, I repeatedly attempted to install the SDK but failed mainly because the connection speed is low and Android studio is poor at downloading files. If I could download the needed files myself, using IDM I could have installed the SDK in 4-5 hours.
Is there a way to offline install Android SDK? When Android studio downloads files, where does it put them temporarily? Can I download SDK files and put them in that temporary folder? Why is Google not providing offline install option? I would appreciate any suggestion.

Note:
Question not answered still. Open for more discussion.

Answer (score 2):

You can download SDK and Android Studio separately. Once download is successful:

Go to `Settings -> Android SDK -> Edit -> Choose path of downloaded directory -> Next -> Ok`

[image: SDK]

Comment: Any link where to download the SDK? I only found command line SDK on Android website.

Comment: @birraa you can download sdk-tools-windows.zip from [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads) link. After that use SdkManager to download other packages

Comment: @birraa its under `tools/bin` folder

Comment: Only batch file named SdkManager, not exe. The batch file does not give me anything when I try to run it. The new sdk-tools is somehow different from the previous sdk-tools.

Comment: @birraa you can check this [official guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager) for its usage

Comment: @birraa great! remember to approve the answer if it was useful

Comment: Sure, I will. Thanks a lot.